# vaadin - delay execution while modal dialog window is open

Tags: multithreading, drag-and-drop, vaadin

I have a **grid layout** in which I want to show a pop up when the user tries to replace a component which is already present in the grid.

For e.g. the grid layout has a Label (wrapped in a DragAndDropWrapper) which is present at 0,0 position.

If the user tries to add a new component at the same position(0,0 position), then it should show a pop up (confirmation dialog box) asking the user to confirm if the user wishes the replace the existing component or not.

Now, my issue is that the current thread does not wait for the execution to complete. It keeps going ahead after showing the pop up box. Thus, there is a lot of problem in updating the UI after the input is taken from the dialog box for the user's answer.

Can someone show how to do this? Note that I need to do this in a DragAndDropHandler's drop method call as I need to show the dialog box only when the user tries to drop a new component on an existing component of the grid layout.

A working example would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your drop handler, remember what the user is trying to drop and then ask for confirmation.
In the case of OK confirmation then add the component at the remembered drop place.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I ended up doing. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed the comment by André Schild and it did work for me.

I just remember which component and location was used for replacing the component. Then, I ask for a confirmation and if the user says Yes, then I just go ahead and replace it.

Thanks again Andre